# How do I create an SSRS report that will drill into a detail report, while opening the detail report in another tab?

Tags: javascript, reporting-services

I've created a SSRS report that drills through to a detail report. The Detail Report then drills into a Sub Detail Report. The current issue is: the end user is requesting that each drill through report open on new tab in the browser.

I figured I'd accomplish this with Javascript in textbox properties. However, I'm not so strong in Javascript syntax. Pasted below is what I've tried:

```
="javascript:void window.open(" &"'"& Globals!ReportServerUrl &"/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?"
&Globals!ReportFolder &"/Data Movement Detail.rdl
&ProcessID="&Parameters!ProcessName.Value &"
&RunID = "&Fields!RunID.Value &"
 ','_blank')"
```

This is not working at all. Any ideas or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Updated attempt below:

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://Yeahyeahyea/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fCorporate+Reports%2fThis+Folder%2fSub+Folder+Detail&ProcessID=Parameters!ProcessName.Value&RunID=Fields!RunID.Value','_blank'))"
```

Comment: You're on the right track. I would test the URL and get it working in a browser before you try to create it in the report. The URL has to be encoded so replace the spaces in your report name with "+". Don't put spaces around the equals after RunID.

Comment: I think the code on the upper section is convoluted and hard to understand. My updated attempt is much closer. But for some reason my parameters are not being passed. Thanks for the insight though.

Comment: There's no ".rdl" in the updated attempt. Also Parameter and Field references need to be outside the string like before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured I'd post a working example of what answered my question for future users:

```
="javascript:void(window.open(" &"'"& Globals!ReportServerUrl &"/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fCorporate+Reports%2fSub+Folder%2fDetail+Report&ProcessID="&Parameters!ProcessName.Value(0) &"&RunID="&Fields!RunID.Value &"','_blank'))"
```

Comment: Wont work if embedding the parent report in an iframe